# Read data from MySQL database for SmartGWT ScatterPlot Chart

Tags: java, mysql, smartgwt

I am creating a smartgwt scatter plot chart but I can't make it read the data in mysql database and display it out. Part of my codes are as below:

ScatterPlotChart.java

```
public class ScatterPlotChart {
    private static FacetChart scatterPlot;
    private static Facet metric;
    private static Facet patient;
    private static DynamicForm typeForm;
    private static SelectItem linesTypeItem;
    public static VStack scatterChartStack;

    public static VStack getScatterPlot() {     
        scatterPlot = new FacetChart();
        scatterPlot.setData(ResultGrid.dataRecords);
        scatterPlot.setID("scatterPlotChart");

        metric = new Facet();
        metric.setValues(new FacetValue("y"), new FacetValue("x"));
        metric.setInlinedValues(true);
        metric.setId("metric");

        patient = new Facet();
        patient.setId("patientID");

        scatterPlot.setFacets(metric, patient);
        scatterPlot.setValueProperty("y");
        scatterPlot.setChartType(ChartType.SCATTER);
        scatterPlot.setTitle("Scatter Plot");
        scatterPlot.setShowScatterLines(true);
        scatterPlot.setDataLineType(DataLineType.SMOOTH);

        scatterChartStack = new VStack(15);
        scatterChartStack.setWidth100();
        scatterChartStack.setHeight(400);
        scatterChartStack.addMembers(scatterPlot);
        scatterChartStack.setVisible(false);

        return scatterChartStack;
    }
}
```

ResultGrid.java

```
public class ResultGrid {
    public static ListGrid resultGrid;
    public static Record[] dataRecords;

    public static ListGrid getResultGrid() {

        resultGrid = new ListGrid();
        resultGrid.setAutoFetchData(true);
        resultGrid.setShowAllRecords(true);
        resultGrid.setCanEdit(false);
        resultGrid.setShowRecordComponents(true);          
        resultGrid.setShowRecordComponentsByCell(true);
        resultGrid.setDataSource(DataSource.get("sampledb"));

        dataRecords = resultGrid.getRecords();

        return resultGrid;
    }
}
```

ResultGrid.java is the listgrid used to display the data in the database, and ScatterPlotChart.java is to draw the scatter plot. In the ResultGrid.java I have ListGridFields and fields are set too. The record array of database i passed through dataRecords. Please help!